# Quick and easy web logic application with multiple back-end servers

Tags: java, weblogic

Looking for a web logic application with multiple back-end servers for performance tooling evaluation.  What would be a good test application that is not too hard to setup (I pretty much a beginner on this).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess WebLogic ships by default with a sample application called Avitek Medical Records (or "MedRec") in its samples. The application is pretty simple to get started with and covers some standard technology stacks. If I am not wrong you can compile it and configure it to use different database servers as well, which might prove important while determining the performance of your tool for different database driver vendors. Apart from the above mentioned application there are various samples from different technology stacks shipped with WebLogic samples which you can use for the performance evaluation.